# Netbeans- NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

The code is running correctly in Gitbash command line (GitHub). However, when I compile and run it in NetBeans, it gives me `NoSuchElement Exception`. I would appreciate if someone can help me with NetBeans.

```
     package MyApp;

     import java.util.Scanner;

     public class MyApp {
     /** 
     * Starts the program 
     * 
     * @param args command line arguments 
     */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // welcome the user to MyApp
        System.out.println("Welcome to MyApp");
        System.out.println();  // print a blank line

        // create a Scanner object named sc
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // check if the number you enter is even or odd until choice isn't
        equal to "y" or "Y"
        String choice = "y";
        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            // get the integer from the user
            System.out.print("Enter an integer:   ");
            double integer = sc.nextDouble();

            // check whether it is even or odd
            if (integer % 2 == 0) {
              System.out.println("It is an even integer");
            } else {
                System.out.println("It is an odd integer");  ;
            }

            // see if the user wants to continue
            System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you run a program using GitHub? And could you please post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I used Gitbash command line (GitHub) to run the code. Error Message-     Enter an integer:   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
 at MyApp.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:31)

Comment: I assume that mixing `next()` and `nextDouble()` may cause the issue. Try to use `Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine())` and `sc.nextLine()`.

Comment: @DasElias Still, I am receiving the same NoSuchElementException                                                       Enter an integer:   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
 at MyApp.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:32)

Comment: Change to `sc.nextInt();`

Comment: @AngeloMendes It doesn't work. It gives an error message saying that string cannot be converted to integer.

Comment: Its work for me: https://onlinegdb.com/r1MjkRFAV. I make the test in NetBeans too.

Comment: @AngeloMendes Thanks for the help. There was problem in Gradle and Maven version of NetBeans. I tried to compile it in the Ant version of NetBeans it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I ran that code, and it works perfectly! The only thing that I changed was at the line

```
    //check if number you entered is even or odd until choice isnt 
    equal to "y" or "Y"
```

I changed this to:

```
    //check if number you entered is even or odd until choice isnt 
    //equal to "y" or "Y"
```

Although sometimes the scanner gets stuck on the previous thing, so you could try to use `sc.nextLine();` so that it will go to the next line and take the new line character.